# Android push notification PHP code not working in 3rd party server, working in local server

Tags: php, android, push-notification

i am just trying to test an app with android push notification (C2DM), I am sure there is nothing wrong with the android code. I am using PHP code to connect to push server and send a message, its working fine in my local server.

But if i run the same in a third party server its not running. It is not giving me any error msgs. and it says "HTTP status 200 OK" as response.

for your reference i am adding the code, i got this from some website.

```
<?php    
    $username ="push_enabled_email_id@gmail.com";  
    $password = "password"; 
    $source="My-Server-Event-Alerter"; //anything that says about ur app  
    $service="ac2dm";  

    // local server
    $message =$_GET ['message']; 

    if ($_GET ['message'] != '' )  
    {  
        $message =$_GET ['message']; 
        echo 'Message sent to server '.$message;  

        $post_params = array( 
                        "Email" => $username, 
                        "Passwd" => $password, 
                        "accountType"=>"HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE", 
                        "source" => $source,
                        "service"=>$service 
                        );   

        $first = true;  
        $data_msg = "";  

        foreach ($post_params as $key => $value)
        {  

            if ($first)  
                $first = false;  
            else  
                $data_msg .= "&";  

            $data_msg .= urlencode($key) ."=". urlencode($value);  
        }

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");  

        $data = array(
                    'accountType' => HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE,  
                    'Email' => $username,
                    'Passwd' => $password,
                    'source'=> $source, 
                    'service'=>$service
                    ); 

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        // for debugging the request
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); // for debugging
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);   
        echo $response;   
        $pos = strpos($response, "Auth=");  
        $authKey = trim(substr($response, 5+$pos));  
        echo $authKey;  

        echo 'Device Token: '. $deviceToken . '';  
        $data = array(  
        'registration_id' => $deviceToken,  
        'collapse_key' => 'ck_' . 'col_key',  
        'data.message' => $message,  
        'data.title' =>'Request Push Demo'
        );  

        //$data = (is_array($data)) ? http_build_query($data) : $data;   

        $ch = curl_init();  

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");  
        echo 'Content-Length:'.strlen($data);  
        $headers = array('Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=' . $authKey,'Content-Length:'.strlen($data));  
        if($headers)
        {  
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        $messagedata = curl_exec($ch);
        //var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch)); //for debugging the request
        //var_dump($messagedata); 
        // echo $messagedata;  
        curl_close($ch);  
    }  
?>  



<html>
<form action ="./c2dmtest2.php" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="Send Notification" target="_self">  
<label>Push Message  
<input name="message" type="text" size="50" maxlength="50"></label>  
<input name="Send Message" type="submit" value="Send Message">  
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you verify that both servers have same extensions installed? Especially CURL? Are there problems with invalid or untrusted SSL connections?
You might have to set CURL to accept any SSL certificate and not validate it.

Comment: Do you get any CURL message from curl_error() ?

Comment: try GCM.time has been changed.

Comment: could you past the output of the var_dump commented in your sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the following lines on top of your code, in order to see potential errors:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```